# How to sort taxonomy facets alphabetically in views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I have created an expose filter using facet indexed field. Added an sort expose filter to it. There is a taxonomy term field. User need to sort that field ASC/DESC alphabetically order.

But it sort depends on taxonomy ID.

Comment: Are you using the Facet API (https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi)?

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who drop by here check [this issue here](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi/issues/2293657)

> Just make sure to have "Display value" at top and checked, put the
>   order as "Ascending" and you are good to go!

[image]
[image]